# Item Drop From Enemy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have some project to make Space Shooter Game

I want to make, when the enemy was shot, It's drop an item like coin and capsule

here my script for enemy

```
 void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        //mendeteksi collision musuh  dengan peswat atau peluru pesawat
        if ((col.tag == "pesawatplayer") || (col.tag == "pelurupesawat"))
        {
            PlayExplosion();
            DropItem(this.transform.position);

            //destroy enemy 
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        
    }
```

And this code DropItem ()

```
void Kill()
{
    ItemDrops = new List<GameObject>();
    ItemDrops.Add(Coin);
    ItemDrops.Add(Capsule);
}

public void DropItem(Vector3 pos)
{
    int num = Random.Range (0,ItemDrops.Count);
    GameObject Item = Instantiate(ItemDrops[num],pos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

    //set position of item drop
    Item.transform.position = transform.position;
   
}
```

I hope you can help me, Thank you

Comment: What are you having trouble with?  You haven't asked anything or stated what your problem with your code is.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you are asking help with. I am interpreting that you are trying to get an item to spawn when an enemy is blown up but it is not working for you.

First, what I would do is create a class to manage how many coins you have. Simply declare ‘public int coins;’ in the beginning of CoinManager script which should be attached to your player. A method to get coins and a method to set coins.

Second, create a prefab that has a sprite2d and a collider2d (I believe that’s what it’s called. I’m having a brain fart at this moment). Then create a script for this prefab that when it runs into the players collider it will update the CoinManager with += 1 coin. And then destroy the GameObject.

Third, on the enemies script create a ‘public GameObject coinPrefab’ reference. Drag the coin prefab to it on the parameters sidebar in unity. Then write a death method that Destroys the current spawns a coin gameobject via ‘ Instantiate(coinPrefab, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);’ and destroys the current gameObject (enemy) via ‘destroy()’.

Read more about it here. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html